# Check if a value appears only once in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, unique

I want to create a table for managing versions of parameters...

In this table there is a column of type `char` that lets me know what version I have to use :

```
create table PARAMETERS_VERSION (
                ID number not null,
                VERSION number not null,
                DATE_START date not null,
                DATE_END date check(DATE_START <= DATE_END) not null
                ISUSED char(1) check(ISUSED in ('Y','N')) not null,
                constraint PARAMETERS_VERSION_VERSION_PK primary key (ID),
                constraint PARAMETERS_VERSION_VERSION_UK unique (ISUSED)
);
```

How to define a unique constraint on the column `ISUSED` to have only a single row with the value '`Y`' (and the others with '`N`') ?

By the way, is my check constraint on `DATE_END` is correct ?

Comment: A single row per ID, right?

Comment: Do you have another table (or columns) that actually store the values of the parameters?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes. ID is the primary key so it's unique.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have others tables who have a foreign key who references PARAMETERS_VERSION.ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesn't quite support partial or filtered indexes.  Instead, you can use a functional index with some cleverness:

```
create unique index idx_parametersversion_isused
    on parameters_version(case when is_used = 'Y' then -1 else id end);
```

That is, when `is_used` has any value other than `Y`, then the primary key is used.  When it is `Y`, then a constant is used, so two values will conflict.